# How to insert DataGridView data in to table of access database using c#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, ms-access-2010

My program first import data from excel to `datagridview`, then create button create a table of `datagridview` in access database, then insert button insert all the data of `datagridview` in to that table.

My query is working fine for some excel data but not for some biggest data which has 1000 of rows of data, I want to change my query which insert all type of data into data base, here is my query:

```
private void Create_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<string> queries = new List<string>();
       queries.Add("CREATE TABLE " + textBox2.Text + " ( [" + DataGridView1.Columns[0].Name + "] Text, [" + DataGridView1.Columns[1].Name + "] Text, [" + DataGridView1.Columns[2].Name + "] Text, [" + DataGridView1.Columns[3].Name + "] Text, [" + DataGridView1.Columns[4].Name + "] Text, [" + DataGridView1.Columns[5].Name + "] Text, [" + DataGridView1.Columns[6].Name + "] Text)"); 


 private void btn_insert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {List<string> queries = new List<string>();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
        { if (!row.IsNewRow)
            {queries.Add("INSERT Into " + textBox2.Text + " (" + DataGridView1.Columns[0].Name + "," + DataGridView1.Columns[1].Name + "," + DataGridView1.Columns[2].Name + "," + DataGridView1.Columns[3].Name + "," + DataGridView1.Columns[4].Name + "," + DataGridView1.Columns[5].Name + "," + DataGridView1.Columns[6].Name + " ) values ('" + row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "','" + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "','" + row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "','" + row.Cells[3].Value.ToString() + "','" + row.Cells[4].Value.ToString() + "','" + row.Cells[5].Value.ToString() + "','" + row.Cells[6].Value.ToString() + "')"); }
        }
        (ExecuteBatchUpdate(queries.ToArray()))
```

Answer (score -1):

```
List<string> queries = new List<string>();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in DataGridView1.Rows)
{
    if (!row.IsNewRow)
    {
        queries.Add("Insert Into employee (empid,empname,sal) values ('" + row.Cells[0].Value.ToString() + "','" + row.Cells[1].Value.ToString() + "','" + row.Cells[2].Value.ToString() + "')");
    }
}
```

Comment: I've fixed the [formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in your answer, but in future you should do this yourself. [From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/19874792).